# awesomeWM: transparent wibar?

Tags: awesome-wm, conky

I use awesomewm and have a small conky configuration on top of my wallpaper with transparent background. Now i have the idea to change the behaviour of awesomewm to let this small area untouched. So when maximising a window (client?) or when arranging them, this small area must be completely free. I tried to add a second wibar on the right side, changed the width and made it transparent. But all i got was a transparent sidebar which shows the background but not the informations comming from conky.

Is it possible to stack two transparent components over the wallpaper? which configuration whould be the best? Is there a better way to reach my goal?

I use Manjaro with awesomewm. I can post configs if needed.

Thanks, Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want "true transparency", you need to run a composite manager like [xcompmgr](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xcompmgr), [compiz](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Compiz) or [compton/picom](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Picom). These are just random examples and all links point to the arch wiki. On [Xorg#Composite](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Composite), it also lists unagi as a possibility, but the wiki does not have a page for it.

Without a composite manager, "fake transparency" is used. Transparency is simulated by taking the wallpaper and drawing that as the background of the wibox. From your description, it sounds like this is what you are seeing.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. On my computer picom was already installed. When i started it, i only had to change one or another config-file and voilá, everything is fine.

maybe using a lightweight wm because of an old computer and additionally using a composite manager because of the fancyness isn't a good idea, but i will try the impact on my cpu ....